# getDefaultSharedPreferences cannot be applied to Adapter.pagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, viewpagerindicator

I'm creating a preference setting for my app, this setting will allow user to change the font size to desirable size, the problem is the TextView content that i want to change is sit inside `ViewPager`. I try to follow tutorials from youtube and other source but it seem like im having problem with this line. 
please refer to the image below and please help me.

[image]

this is my class name and it extending pager adapter

```
public class TawafPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
```

Comment: You need to provide a `context` to your `TawafPagerAdapter` class and then pass that `context` to `getDefaultSharedPreferences`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by passing the context to the fragment and use `context`instead of `this`

```
public TawafPagerAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}
```

then write this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String setFontSize = mySharedPreferences.getString("RomanFontSizeKey", "");
```